# How to obtain Multiple subtotals using SQL and VBS from Access Table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript

I am trying to obtain multiple subtotals from an Access Table , using a external vbs file vbscript in Windows.

```
mySQL = "SELECT [Data.Time],"& Quantity &"*Sum([Data.Price]) AS 
SumOfPrice FROM Data WHERE (  ( [Data.Ticker] Like '"& CE1 &"'  
Or [Data.Ticker] Like '"& CE2 &"' Or [Data.Ticker] Like '"& CE3 &"' 
Or [Data.Ticker] Like '"& CE4 &"' Or [Data.Ticker] Like '"& CE5 &"' 
Or [Data.Ticker] Like '"& PE1 &"' Or [Data.Ticker] Like '"& PE2 &"' 
Or [Data.Ticker] Like '"& PE3 &"' Or [Data.Ticker] Like '"& PE4 &"' 
Or [Data.Ticker] Like '"& PE5 &"' 
 ) AND ([Data.DateTr]=#"& DateIn &"#))
 GROUP BY [Data.Time] HAVING [Data.Time] > #"& startTime(i) &"# and (((Count([Data.Ticker]))= 10))"
```

Further Processing....

```
objRecordSet2.Open mySQL,objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
objRecordSet2.MoveFirst     
Do Until objRecordSet2.EOF
    If objRecordSet2.Fields.Item(1) > testvalue
```

Presently it provides the total of CE+PE for each time (every 1 minute)
Must ensure exactly 5 CE records and 5 PE records for every time instant , hence total 10.

Can we Modify it to provide totals of CE and PE seperately.
SELECT Time , SumofCEPrice , SumofPEPrice for each 1 minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add, *Ticker* as another grouping variable in `GROUP BY`. Additionally consider below items:

- Any `LIKE` expression without a wildcard operator, `%` or `*`, is redundant and should use the equality, `=`. In fact, here you can use even an `IN()` clause;
- Non-aggregated columns should be left out of `HAVING` and placed in `WHERE` clause;
- Use parameterization which is supported by DAO and ADO connections.

Adjusted SQL string

```vb
"SELECT [Data.Time], [Data.Ticker], "& Quantity &" * Sum([Data.Price]) AS SumOfPrice " & _
" FROM Data " & _
" WHERE ( " & _
"           ( [Data.Ticker] = '"& CE1 &"'  " & _
"            OR [Data.Ticker] = '"& CE2 &"' OR [Data.Ticker] = '"& CE3 &"' " & _
"            OR [Data.Ticker] = '"& CE4 &"' OR [Data.Ticker] = '"& CE5 &"' " & _
"            OR [Data.Ticker] = '"& PE1 &"' OR [Data.Ticker] = '"& PE2 &"' " & _
"            OR [Data.Ticker] = '"& PE3 &"' OR [Data.Ticker] = '"& PE4 &"' " & _
"            OR [Data.Ticker] = '"& PE5 &"' " & _
"           ) " & _
"           AND ([Data.DateTr] = #" & DateIn & "#)" & _
"           AND ([Data.Time] > #" & startTime(i) & "#) " & _
"       ) " & _
" GROUP BY [Data.Time], [Data.Ticker] " & _
" HAVING Count(([Data.Ticker]) = 10)"
```

Alternatively, use parameterization with [ADO Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/createparameter-method-ado?view=sql-server-2017):

```vb
' PREPARED STATEMENT (NO DATA)
mySQL = "SELECT [Data.Time], [Data.Ticker], ? * Sum([Data.Price]) AS SumOfPrice " & _
        " FROM Data " & _
        " WHERE ([Data.Ticker] IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,  " & _
        "                          ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) " & _
        "   AND ([Data.DateTr] = ?) " & _
        "   AND ([Data.Time] > ?) " & _
        " GROUP BY [Data.Time], [Data.Ticker] " & _
        " HAVING Count(([Data.Ticker]) = 10)"

Set objCmd = New ADODB.Command

With objCmd
   .ActiveConnection = objConnection
   .CommandText = mySQL
   .CommandType = adCmdText

   ' BIND PARAMETERS CORRESPONDING TO ORDER OF ? PLACEMARKERS
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pmQty", adInteger, adParamInput, , Quantity)

   For Each var In Array(CE1, CE2, CE3, CE4, CE5, PE1, PE2, PE3, PE4, PE5)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, var)
   Next var

   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pmDateIn", adDate, adParamInput, , DateIn)
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pmStartTime", adDBTime, adParamInput, , startTime(i))

   ' BUILD RECORDSET FROM EXECUTION
   Set objRecordSet2 = .Execute
End With

objRecordSet2.MoveFirst     
Do Until objRecordSet2.EOF
    If objRecordSet2.Fields.Item(1) > testvalue
```

Comment: Thanks for rectifying the SQL. However , how do we take out the sum of ce1+ce2+ce3+ce4+ce5 and pe1+pe1+pe3+pe4+pe5 seperately.
Ensuring to use only where all 10 records are available and corespond to same time.

Comment: You can add a calculated column as a grouping: `IIF([Ticker] IN ('CE1', 'CE2', 'CE3', ...), 'C Group', IIF([Ticker] IN ('PE1', 'PE2', 'PE3', ...), 'P Group', NULL))`, replacing *Ticker* and `HAVING` clause. But this appears to be a different question. Curious did above solution (especially recommended parameterization) help resolve current issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional aggregation by changing your `select` statement to:

```
"SELECT [Data.Time]," & Quantity & "*Sum(iif([Data.Ticker] Like '" & CE1 & "' or [Data.Ticker] Like '" & CE2 & "' or [Data.Ticker] Like '" & CE3 & "' or [Data.Ticker] Like '" & CE4 & "' or [Data.Ticker] Like '" & CE5 & "',[Data.Price],0)) AS SumofCEPrice "
```

With a `SumofPEPrice` column built in a similar manner.

Comment: Thanks. Trying now. 
both ce and pe should corespond to same time instant and also both categories should be 5 , skip any record if any shortage in CE or PE. 
The count function , (((Count([Data.Ticker]))=10)) , after having will work in case if is used ?