# How to use PIVOT on SQL with additional criteria like colum count check and grouping?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript, pivot

Present output of the  below SQL query is :

```
Time | SumValue(CE+PE)
```

2 columns -  ensuring the number of output is exactly ten.

How can I transpose it to :

```
Time | CE1Value | CE2Value |... |CE5Value | PE1Value | ... PE5Value
```

11 columns.

Ensuring that there are all the ten records for the same specific time , else skip to the next minute (next record).
I am assuming that it is sorted by time,by default else can I use order by - is it optimum.

Using a standalone vbs file in windows against data in MS Access.

```
mySQL = "SELECT [Data.Time],"& Quantity &"*Sum([Data.Price]) AS SumOfPrice FROM Data WHERE (  ( [Data.Ticker] Like '"& CE1 &"'  Or [Data.Ticker] Like '"& CE2 &"' Or [Data.Ticker] Like '"& CE3 &"' Or [Data.Ticker] Like '"& CE4 &"' Or [Data.Ticker] Like '"& CE5 &"' Or [Data.Ticker] Like '"& PE1 &"'  Or [Data.Ticker] Like '"& PE2 &"'  Or [Data.Ticker] Like '"& PE3 &"'  Or [Data.Ticker] Like '"& PE4 &"'  Or [Data.Ticker] Like '"& PE5 &"'  ) AND ([Data.DateTr]=#"& DateIn &"#)) GROUP BY [Data.Time] HAVING [Data.Time] > #"& startTime(i) &"# and (((Count([Data.Ticker]))=10))"
```

---

Eg. For understanding : 
The data table is :

```
DateTr|Ticker|Time|Price
22July2016|Apple|3:20 AM|15
22July2016|Apple|3:21 AM|16
22July2016|Apple|3:23 AM|14
22July2016|Amazon|3:20 AM|16
22July2016|Amazon|3:21 AM|14
22July2016|Amazon|3:22 AM|14
22July2016|Amazon|3:23 AM|14
```

Eg. Apple data is for 3:22 , so skip and move onto next.
But ensure for the same time - the count is two (in this case Apple+Amazon) ten in my case. CE1 = Apple , PE1 = Amazon
Earlier Output :

```
3:20|31
3:21|30
3:23|28
```

New Output required :

```
3:20|15|16
3:21|16|14
so on.
```

Ticker is matched with CE1 , CE2 , PE2 etc.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like PIVOT command has to be used. Finding it a bit complex. Can you please help.

Comment: @parfait , removed the tag. can you please help with the sql query - struggling with it since last few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data resides in MS Access, consider the [crosstab query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8) which you can explicitly specify the 10 columns with `PIVOT` clause:

```sql
TRANSFORM SUM(t.Price) As SumPrice
SELECT t.[Time]
FROM mytable t
GROUP BY t.[Time]
PIVOT t.ticker IN ('Apple', 'Cisco', 'Oracle', 'Microsoft', 'IBM',
                   'Amazon', 'Alphabet', 'Intel', 'Adobe', 'SAP')
```

Alternatively, run the conditional aggregation, again explicitly specifying the 10 columns with 10 expressions. This approach allows the flexibility of renaming columns such as suffixing *_Value*.

```sql
SELECT t.Time,
       SUM(IIF(t.ticker = 'Apple', t.Price, NULL)) AS CE1_Value,
       SUM(IIF(t.ticker = 'Cisco', t.Price, NULL)) AS CE2_Value,
       SUM(IIF(t.ticker = 'Oracle', t.Price, NULL)) AS CE3_Value,
       ...
       SUM(IIF(t.ticker = 'Amazon', t.Price, NULL)) AS PE1_Value,
       SUM(IIF(t.ticker = 'Alphabet', t.Price, NULL)) AS PE2_Value,
       SUM(IIF(t.ticker = 'Intel', t.Price, NULL)) AS PE3_Value,
       ...
FROM mytable t
GROUP BY t.Time
```

---

Should values need to be passed into query, as I recommended in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55360778/1422451) consider ADO parameterization. Alternatively, with DAO (Access' default API) you can save a prepared statement as an Access query object using `PARAMETERS` clause and bind values in code using [QueryDefs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydef-object-dao) at runtime. Both approaches avoid messy concatenation and punctuation as seen in your *mysql* variable.

#### DAO

**SQL** *(save as an Access query; no quotes or concatenation)*

```sql
PARAMETERS [DateIn] Date, [Qty_Param] Long,
           [CE1_Param] Text, [CE2_Param] Text, [CE3_Param] Text, [CE4_Param] Text, [CE5_Param] Text, 
           [PE1_Param] Text, [PE2_Param] Text, [PE3_Param] Text, [PE4_Param] Text, [PE5_Param] Text;
SELECT t.DateTr, t.[Time],
       [Qty_Param] * SUM(IIF(t.ticker = [CE1_Param], t.Price, NULL)) AS CE1_Value,
       [Qty_Param] * SUM(IIF(t.ticker = [CE2_Param], t.Price, NULL)) AS CE2_Value,
       [Qty_Param] * SUM(IIF(t.ticker = [CE3_Param], t.Price, NULL)) AS CE3_Value,
       ...
       [Qty_Param] * SUM(IIF(t.ticker = [PE1_Param], t.Price, NULL)) AS PE1_Value,
       [Qty_Param] * SUM(IIF(t.ticker = [PE2_Param], t.Price, NULL)) AS PE2_Value,
       [Qty_Param] * SUM(IIF(t.ticker = [PE3_Param], t.Price, NULL)) AS PE3_Value,
       ...
FROM mytable t
WHERE t.DateTr = [DateIn])
GROUP BY t.DateTr, t.[Time]
```

**VBA**

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset, qdef As DAO.QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")

With qdef
    .Parameters("DateIn") = CDate("2016-07-22")
    .Parameters("Qty_Param") = ###
    .Parameters("CE1_Param") = "Apple"
    .Parameters("CE2_Param") = "..."
    .Parameters("CE3_Param") = "..."
    ...
    .Parameters("PE1_Param") = "Amazon"
    .Parameters("PE2_Param") = "..."
    .Parameters("PE3_Param") = "..."
    ...
End With

Set rst = qdef.OpenRecordset()

...

rst.Close: qdef.Close
Set rst = Nothing: Set qdef = Nothing: Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: thanks. I will use the DAO approach.
The problem I am facing is that  , I have to ensure that there are ten columns (available data) for the same given time. Please see the AppleAmazon eg. you will understand.

Comment: No Summation is required , only time and the ten columns of prices. ensuring there are ten columns if data is missing skip to next.

Comment: As mentioned, both these solutions explicitly render 10 columns. I updated to reflect your data. Also, `SUM` does not matter. Any aggregate (`AVG`, `MIN`, `MAX`, etc.) will return the same if only *ticker* per *time* results.

Comment: Thanks Working Perfectly. Used Is Not Null and saving the query , will use parameters.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Below is my final, working SQL code.

```sql
SELECT Data.Time, 
       Round(Sum(IIf(Data.Ticker='Apple',Data.price,Null)),2) AS CE1_Value, 
       Round(Sum(IIf(Data.Ticker='Amazon',Data.price,Null)),2) AS CE2_Value, 
       Round(Sum(IIf(Data.Ticker='Intel',Data.price,Null)),2) AS PE1_Value, 
       Round(Sum(IIf(Data.ticker='Microsoft',Data.price,Null)),2) AS PE2_Value 
FROM Data 
WHERE (((Data.Time)>#12/30/1899 12:20:0#) AND ((Data.DateTr)=#6/18/2019#)) 
GROUP BY Data.Time, Data.DateTr 
HAVING (((Sum(IIf(Data.Ticker='Apple',Data.price,Null))) Is Not Null) 
   AND  ((Sum(IIf(Data.Ticker='Amazon',Data.price,Null))) Is Not Null) 
   AND  ((Sum(IIf(Data.Ticker='Intel',Data.price,Null))) Is Not Null) 
   AND  ((Sum(IIf(Data.ticker='Microsoft',Data.price,Null))) Is Not Null)) 
ORDER BY Data.Time;
```

Comment: `HAVING` clause is verbose and redundant. Simply use a `WHERE` clause on your tickers: `WHERE Data.ticker in ('Apple', 'Amazon', 'Microsoft', 'Intel')`. But even this is redundant as the conditional aggregates only sums if these values show up otherwise assign as `NULL` which is excluded from aggregated sums